# Lazy repartitioning of dask dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

After several stages of lazy dataframe processing, I need to repartition my dataframe before saving it. However, the `.repartition()` method requires me to know the number of partitions (as opposed to size of partitions) and that depends on size of the data after processing, which is yet unknown.

I think I can do lazy calculation of size by `df.memory_usage().sum()` but `repartition()` does not seem to accept it (scalar) as an argument.

Is there a way to do this kind of adaptative (data-size-based) lazy repartitioning?

PS. Since this is the (almost) last step in my pipeline, I can probably work around this by converting to delayed and repartitioning "manually" (I don't need to go back to dataframe), but I'm looking for a simpler way to do this.

PS. Repartitioning by partition size would also be a very useful feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Dask's task-graph construction happens immediately and there is no way to partition (or do any operation) in a way where the number of partitions is not immediately known or is lazily computed.

You could, as you suggest, switch to lower-level systems like delayed.  In this case I would switch to using [futures](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html) and track the size of results as they came in, triggering appropriate merging of partitions on the fly.  This is probably far more complex than is desired though.

Comment: Just to follow up on this one, I ended up converting dataframe to delayed and constructed a chain of delayed functions that would merge partitions (by passing them along) into big enough chunks to be written/uploaded. This is a bit slow, but preserves parition order and works for me because I need this repartitioning only for the purpose of storage.